# Why would calling a child_process command work with exec but not spawn?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, child-process

Why would this work:

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;
var command = exec("grunt");
```

But this throws an error:

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var command = spawn("grunt");
```

The error it throws is `Error: spawn ENOENT`

At first I thought it might have something to do with the `env`, but it is exactly the same in both `exec` and `spawn.`  I think it must somehow have something to do with Grunt, since trying `git` works in both.

Answer (score 3):

On checking the node [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) for `spawn` I found:

> Note that if spawn receives an empty options object, it will result in
>   spawning the process with an empty environment rather than using
>   process.env. This due to backwards compatibility issues with a
>   deprecated API.

The default option for `env` in exec is `null`, but for spawn it is `process.env`. So it is ambiguous if both are getting same `env`? Can you check this by giving same `env` explicitly for both.

Comment: Also, you may need to add the file extension of the process you want to spawn (that's what I had to do in my case, which was different to exec)

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem. It only appears on Windows platform. And finally, I found [**this issue**](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2318) that helped me out of this stuff.

I followed `isaacs` suggestion:

> The cmd is either "sh" or "cmd" depending on platform, and the arg is
>   always either /c $cmd or -c $cmd.
>
> ```
> child = child_process.spawnShell('util.bat glerp gorp', {options...})
> ```
>
> Which would be sugar for:
>
> ```
> child = child_process.spawn(isWin ? 'cmd' : 'sh', [isWin?'/c':'-c', arg], options)
> ```

Then, I wrote my own simple `spawnShell`:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;    
function spawnShell(args,options){
    var isWin = (process.platform === 'win32');
    args.unshift(isWin ? '/c' : '-c');
    return spawn(isWin ? 'cmd' : 'sh', args, options);
}
```

Although it's a little late, hopefully my answer still can help somebody else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, child_process.exec "Spawns a shell then executes the command within that shell", while child_process.spawn "spawns a new process using the given command". A shell, such as bash is an application that lets you execute compiled binaries defined in locations specified by the [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). Exec behaves the same way as the shell it spawns, while spawn looks for compiled binaries in your PATH directly (probably by calling the C function execvp). I don't know the specifics of grunt, but it is likely not a compiled binary on your path, and probably gets added to the shell context a different way such as an alias in your .bashrc